# How to run Node.js from my computer

Tags: node.js, localhost

I want to show a friend something I wrote in Node.js.
In order to do so I must run a local machine but I can't get it to work out of 127.0.0.1.

I am trying to run: `server.listen(8000, '123.123.123.123');` (with my real IP of course) and I get "Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL".

It does work via 127.0.0.1:8000 when I execute: `server.listen(8000);`.
When I try to access 123.123.123.123:8000 after doing that firefox is "unable to connect".

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to set up port forwarding. port `80` is forwarded automatically you can listen on that instead (use `sudo` to bind to it)

Comment: I forgot to mention I am on windows.
Any way I don't think port 80 would work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple solution is to use a port forwarding tool. Here are three:

- [proxylocal](http://proxylocal.com/) is free and open source.
- [showoff.io](http://showoff.io/) has a nice design and really cheap day passes.
- [pagekite](http://pagekite.net/) bills based on data usage and has a generous trial.

To make your above example work with showoff.io, you would need to have a ruby environment and a showoff.io account and type:

```
> gem install showoff-io
> show 8000

share this URL: 
https://youraccountname.showoff.io
```

(It would ask for your password after typing `show 8000`.)

Then your friend could visit the URL showoff gives you.

Comment: Thank you! proxylocal did the job :)

Comment: Ben: I met the same problem, but What's the reason we need port forwarding in a localmachine?

Comment: Kit: To get around firewalls that block incoming traffic.